# Large Tuples with Negative Integers

Tags: memory

I am trying to run a loop that cycles through the elements of Tuples[{-1,0,1},116] and terminates when a desired result is found.

Unfortunately, this creates a memory problem due to 116.  All of the workarounds that I can find, like IntegerDigits, seem to require positive entries in my tuples.

Is there a good technique to help with this?

Comment: You're trying to loop through 22185312344622607535965183080365494317672538611578408721 values?  Good luck.

Comment: Umm, that's 3^116 tuples. How do you propose to cycle through them? As for using IntegerDigits, one can take the digits base 3 of some number between 0 and 3^116, and subtract 1 from all digits.

Comment: I do appreciate how big 3^116 is.  For the record, I never had any intention of cycling through ALL of these tuples... just enough for my purposes.

Comment: @RossElliot  The question indicates ALL, I think.  Maybe you should edit it to say "some" or how many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only a few, then randomly choosing them would be easy and perhaps sufficient.  The following will produce `n = 10` tuples.

```
With[{n = 10},
 NestWhile[
  DeleteDuplicates @ Join[#, RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {n - Length[#], 116}]] &,
  {}, 
  Length[#] < n &]
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

As others said, there are `3^116` such tuples, so no existing computer will be able to cycle through them in reasonable time.  Just to put it in some context, it would take a 1 GHz CPU $3^{116}/10^9/3600/24/365.25 = 7\times 10^{38}$ years to go through this many clock cycles, which is many orders of magnitude longer than the age of the universe.

Recommended reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability

But putting all that aside, there might be situations when you can't pre-generate all the tuples you need to loop through because you don't have enough memory.  So what's a good way to loop though them without keeping all of them in memory?  Here's one suggestion:

```
n = 10; (* 116 is excessive *)
symbols = {-1, 0, 1};

Do[
  (* do something with ... *)
  symbols[[ 1 + IntegerDigits[i, Length[symbols], n] ]]
  ,
  {i, Length[symbols]^n}
]
```